# a = b = 0 in Python

Tags: python, list

I was practicing some algorithms, and I once saw this code

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def addTwoNumbers(self, l1: Optional[ListNode], l2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        
        q = 0
        head = new_LN = ListNode(0)
         
        while l1 or l2:
            l1_val = l1.val if l1 else 0
            l2_val = l2.val if l2 else 0
            q, r = divmod(q + l1_val + l2_val , 10)
            new_LN.next = ListNode(r)
            new_LN = new_LN.next
            l1 = l1.next if l1 else None
            l2 = l2.next if l2 else None
        if q:
            new_LN.next = ListNode(q)
            
        return head.next
```

```
    # print(new_LN) # ListNode{val: 8, next: None}
    # print(head) # ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 7, next: ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 8, next: None}}}}
```

In an example, the results of new_LN and head are stated above.

I cannot understand why head and new_LN are different though they were declared on the same line.

Can anybody explain this one for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to understand is that both `head` and `new_LN` are pointers to an object and not the object itself, so at the beginning of the code when the line  `head = new_LN = ListNode(0)` is called a new ListNode object is created and both `head` and `new_LN` are pointing to it.
but when the line `new_LN = new_LN.next` is called, the pointer `new_LN` is set to point to another object while `head` still points to the original node,
so that's why at the end of  the code `head` and `new_LN` are not equal

hope I could clarify that for you
if you have any questions feel free to ask me in the comments,
and if my comment helped you marking it as the answer or upvoting will go a long way :)

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers — it has *names*. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Thank you for replying the question!

Then my another question is that why head is updated continuously?
Although new_LN is declared newly, but the results are being stacked to head!!

Comment: I don't think `head` gets updated at all, in my opinion, your code only updates `new_LN `